# Open file in __init__() python

Tags: python, file, init

Hey I have a following problem, I need to open a file in `__init__()`, and with `check` function I need to check if strings/numbers in rows of this file are the same or not. If they aren't it should return `True` if they are it should return `False`, and if there are no more lines `None`. I do not know how many lines are there going to be in the file. My code is working kind of, tester is giving me 90%, but it says I do not close the file, I understand why it is saying, but do not know where to put the close. However if I opened it with `with` it should be working but I do not know how to get it working that way.

My Code:

```
class Program:
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.t = open(file_name, 'r')

    def check(self):
        row = self.t.readline()

        array = []

        for i in row.split():
            if i not in array:
                array.append(i)

        if row.split() == []:
            return None
        elif array == row.split():
            return True
        else:
            return False

"""
#testing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    u = Program('file.txt')
    z = True
    while z is not None:
        z = u.check()
        print(z)

"""
```

Example file:

```
15 9 22
2014 2015 2014 2015
p py pyt pyth pytho python
ab ab ab ab ab
```

Comment: Yes, you never `close` the file. Is the file small enough that you can just read it into memory? Or could you structure your own code as a context manager?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not sure if I exactly understand the second part of the question, but the file should not be somewhat big, you can see the example file up, so it should be similar size, or just a few more lines.

Comment: If your class has two methods, one of which is `__init__()`, it shouldn't be a class but a function.

Comment: So why not keep the *content* of the file, rather than the file handle? Then you can `close` the file in `__init__`.

Comment: @RolandSmith I was given a structure, where there was `class Program`, `def __init__()`, and `def check` and I had to work around with this

Comment: why do you need to open the file in `__init__` rather than in the method where you actually use the file?  and as Roland said, why do you even need a class here?

Comment: @Anentropic Also this was said in my task, that I need to open it in `__init__()`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am sorry, but can you please explain that a little more, I am sorry but I am just learning python, and also struggling with english, so I did not fully get your comment.

Comment: then I agree @jonrsharpe's suggestion... read the contents of the file into an attribute (eg an array of lines) in your `__init__` method and then use that in the `check` method

Comment: @Matis Classes can be great, but they are also [overused](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0). See the video that I linked to for a more thorough explanation. [Simple is better than complex](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: @RolandSmith It sounds like this is a class assignment, where for some reason the instructor has insisted that the above structure be used. But I agree with you: if that's all there is to this assignment, then this should be a function, not a class.

Comment: @RolandSmith Thank you for the video, and as jme said, it is an class assignment. And I had to do it this way, I had to use the class and all the structure that is above. Sometimes you have to do silly things, but you have to do them.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I probably can't just keep the content of the file, as the testing area says it will be running until in finds an empty line, I could maybe add one empty line at the end, but don't know how would the tester react to that.

Comment: Is `close()` in `__del__` a good practice? Any body can comment on this solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you open the file in one method and use it in another, you can't use the `with` statement internal to the class. You can add a method to close the file and let the closing be the caller's problem. A popular solution for the caller is to use `contextlib.closing`. Putting it all together...

```
class Program:
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.t = open(file_name, 'r')

    def check(self):
        ...

    def close(self):
        if self.t:
            self.t.close()
            self.t = None


import contextlib
with contextlib.closing(Program('myfile.txt')) as program:
    program.check()
```

Comment: What happens if we just call close from __del__(self)?

Comment: @Mr.WorshipMe - Good question. It would make sense to also call close in the `__del__`. Whether that is sufficient depends on other design goals. For instance, class instances may live a long time after the `with` clause but it may be desirable to close the file as soon as possible. There is a risk that the `__del__` call is deferred on some python implementations leaving the file open or circular reference delay the close until garbage collection.

Comment: The problem is, __del__ is called AFTER the object has been dereferenced (when references to the class object are zero), meaning the name holding the open file no longer exists when you call __del__.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should instantiate the class and the "check" method should check one row at a time.

This works, but if your teacher has not told you about the `yield` statement he will know you are cheating:

```
class Program(object):
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.line_checker = self.make_checker(fname)

    def make_checker(self, fname):
        with open(fname) as i:
            for line in i:
                yield len(set(line.split())) < 2

    def check(self):
        try:
            return self.line_checker.next()
        except StopIteration:
            return None
```