# Accessing class file from multiple methods in Python

Tags: python, file, with-statement

My question relates mostly to how you use the `with` keyword in a class in Python.

If you have a Class which contains a file object, how do you use the `with` statement, if at all.

For example, I don't use `with` here:

```
class CSVLogger:
    def __init__(self, rec_queue, filename):
        self.rec_queue = rec_queue
        ## Filename specifications
        self.__file_string__ = filename
        f = open(self.__file_string__, 'wb')
        self.csv_writer = csv.writer(f,  newline='', lineterminator='\n', dialect='excel')
```

If I then do things to the file in another method, For example:

```
    def write_something(self, msg):
        self.csv_writer(msg)
```

Is this suitable? Should I include the `with` somewhere? I'm just afraid that one the `__init__` exits, the `with` exits and might close the file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27574601/742269

Comment: Never give your own attributes or methods double-underscores on both sides. Those names are intended for Python's own attributes, which you may override, but not define your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct `with` automatically closes the file when its scope ends, so if you use `with` statement in your `__init__()` function, the write_something function would not work.

Maybe you can use the `with` statement in the main part of the program, and instead of opening the file in `__init__()` function you can pass in the file object as a parameter to the `__init__()` function. and then do all operations you would like to do in the file within the `with` block.

Example -

Class would look like -

```
class CSVLogger:
    def __init__(self, rec_queue, filename, f):
        self.rec_queue = rec_queue
        ## Filename specifications
        self.__file_string__ = filename
        self.csv_writer = csv.writer(f,  newline='', lineterminator='\n', dialect='excel')
    def write_something(self, msg):
        self.csv_writer(msg)
```

The main program may look like -

```
with open('filename','wb') as f:
    cinstance = CSVLogger(...,f) #file and other parameters
    .... #other logic
    cinstance.write_something("some message")
    ..... #other logic
```

Though if this complicates thing a-lot, you are better off not using the `with` statement and rather making sure that you close the file when when its need is over.